# How to find table_array referenced in Excel formula in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was given an Excel spreadsheet that I have to convert into a SQL view.

In the cell formulas VLOOKUP is used and for almost all of the table_arrays I can find where the table_array is. But for one particular table_array I can't find it in any of the other sheets. I also have this same problem with a variable.

Is there an function where it will just automatically bring me to the variable or table_array?

Answer (score 5):

Clicking Formulas->Name Manager brings me to a pop-up that tells me all of this information

Answer (score 3):

To expand on TruthOf42's answer, you can display *visible* names in *visible* sheets using:

Formulas → Name Manager

If you have hidden sheets, you may need to unhide them using:

Home → Cells → Format → Visibility → Unhide Sheet

If you *still* can't find your named range, it may be that it was hidden using some vbscript. You can unhide all named ranges in your workbook by doing the following:

1. Open Developer Tools (Alt + F11)
2. Insert → Module
3. Add the following code:

   ```
   Sub ShowNames()
       Dim xName As Name
       For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
           xName.Visible = False
       Next
   End Sub
   ```
4. Execute (F5)